# If a choice is made, will it create a singularity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, quantum-interpretations, singularities

When I watched videos of a TV show named "Star vs the forces of evil" on Youtube, there was a video about the main character - Star - being forced to solve a Math problem, because all versions of Star in parallel universes had solve the Math problem. If she didn't, according to the plot, all parallel universes will be destroyed as well.

Then I scrolled down on the comment section and found a funny comment said that "there will always be a parallel universe where Star didn't do the Math". I remember that I have seen a seemingly scientific reply to the comment, claiming that if a version of Star did the Math, a **singularity** would be created, and all Star versions must do the Math problem as well.

I'm afraid that I can neither remember the source of the video nor the comments of that video, but I remembered the **singularity** word.

**So my question is:** *Is the many worlds theory related to some kind of a singularity?*

I am just a Physics enthusiast, not a true Physicist (yet). Sorry for my English and my amateur opinion.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just a TV show story and has nothing to do with physics. While the many worlds interpretation is a (debated) part of physics, human choices are *not* a part of it. It is also unclear what kind of singularity the show talks about; often the word is just used because it sounds cool.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Thank you. Actually, the "singularity" word was used in the reply,  not in the show. What I want to ask is whether the many worlds theory relates to a singularity or not. I will edit my question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 'Many worlds' is the name of a collection of ideas about how to understand the underlying reality of a set of mathematical models in physics called quantum theory. Many Worlds has nothing to do with singularities, per se.